# Why does Blender say “Python script failed, check the message in the system console” when trying to import a Blender Python file from SynthEyes?

Tags: python

I am new to SynthEyes and I just tracked something but when I try to import it to Blender it just says:

> Python script failed, check the message in the system console.

When I check the system console it says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "\3d Camera Track.py", line
> 3, in  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Blender' Error:
> Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Answer (score 2):

**It's for version 2.49b or before.**

If the script is trying to `import Blender` assume it is written for Blender version 2.49 and before.

Script will need to be upgraded (or search for upgraded version)  using  `bpy` for later version.

Comment: Im using blender 2.83.1

Comment: Sure. ... but the script is for 2.49b @Daniel